# Python - fastest way to search if a string exists in entire excel workbook?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list with a few thousand strings. I need to search for those strings in all columns on all worksheets of an excel workbook. Workbook has 20+ sheets and thousands of rows each worksheet.

If I get any hit, I need to store the hit on another list. The following was able to get it done but was slow.

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile('testfile.xlsx')
worksheets = xl.sheet_names

foundlist = []

for x in worksheets:
    df = xl.parse(x, dtype=str)
    dfcolumns = list(df.columns)
    for c in dfcolumns:
        for z in my_list:
            if df[c].str.contains(z).any():
                foundlist.append(z)
                continue
```

Looking for a faster way to do the search.

Bonus would be also to copy the row of all (not any) hits (don't need header) and storing them all in one dataframe. This I am not sure how to do and trying to figure it out.

Thanks and any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so there are different ways to speed up this code depending on your use case.

- Firstly, while loading the columns of each dataFrame, convert it into a set and do

```
if string in set:
....
```

This helps makes your searching in constant time ( O(1) ). This is because sets are basically hash tables

- If you're going to be using this code many times, it would be unwise to keep loading the dataframe and its columns again and again. For this, you can make use of [Flashtext](https://github.com/vi3k6i5/flashtext), where you have to just load all your columns into the keyword processor just once. Flashtext can make your search much faster
- Another great method is to use  [Dask](https://dask.org/), a library that implements parallel processing native in pandas, and this can greatly optimize your searching

Do take a look at these options. Their documentation is very crisp and clear